# Twilio Autopilot, getting it to understand Alphanumeric responses

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-functions

When we ask a user a question that requires letter & numbers in response (voice / on phone), the system always misinterprets what the user says.  For example, if they response "ABC123" twilio will send us "Hey Be See one two three".  Which when planning on using the response to verify the user via API, makes it unusable.

This is using the Twilio control panel.

Searched and tried different data types at Twilio.  Can't find any way, though seems like it'd be a very common thing.

```
{
    "question": "What is your code ?",
    "name": "Code"
}
```

> Input is: "ABC123"
>
> Output should be "ABC123"
>
> **Output comes out as "Hey Be See one two three"**

Comment: Hey this is Nico from the Autopilot team. Alphanumeric field capture is something we know is not working well as you point out. We are currently working on an Alphanumeric field that will dramatically improve the performance here.

Comment: I read somewhere that you were hoping to have this ready by June.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.
That is a known issue :( The alphanumeric field type that would be the way to handle these is on the product roadmap.
Maybe try using the `Gather` verb in the meantime? Hope this helps <3 
You could use it in a Twilio Function and connect it to Autopilot by redirecting to the Function like so:

```
"on_complete": {
    "redirect": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "https://replace-with-your-function-url.twil.io/example-autopilot"
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see 'gather' on the autopilot API, how exactly would this be done?  When I try to add it to the task's JSON in the Twilio console it does not recognize it.

Comment: You could write the Node.js code that contains `Gather` in a Twilio Function and connect it to Autopilot with your Function URL. I updated the answer to reflect connecting your Autopilot assistant to Functions.

Comment: So right now I have the JSON in the twilio console asking a few questions, and then sending the results to our URL (PHP).  Where I just have it manually output some JSON to basically say 'Thank You'  If I were to manually have the response of the URL contain the gather verb, what would that look like?    Or would it HAVE to basically contain different voice code containing the gather command.  If so, I think even a small snippet of what that PHP code should look like would help.  (seems since autopilot is new, not a whole lot of documentation).

Comment: I haven't used Autopilot with PHP and don't write PHP, but probably something like this, just adding `Gather` to what you have with 'Thank You': https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather

Comment: I actually just tried a test with straight up voice / TwiML.  Even tried to use hints for A,B,C etc..  And it still, very often, comes back with the word instead.  (e.g. Be, See etc..).  Is there a way to restrict the input solely to letters/numbers?  Code:

<Gather input="speech" action="phonedataVIN.php" hints="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0">
           <Say voice="Polly.Matthew">Please say your Member number, one letter or number at a time.</Say>
        </Gather>

Comment: So I have the gather verb, with hints of all letters and numbers, and it is still very unusable.  Returns words instead of letters.  I just need to know if Twilio is capable of understanding letters or not.  If there is no way for Twilio to understand letters being spoken, will have to go elsewhere, but would just like to know a straight answer if it is possible or not.